# email after saving to database

Tags: php

Hi i have a fom with a drop down box and a textbox, the drop down box has usernames and emails as their value. I have code that save to the database and code to email but now when it saves to the database the username is not stored only the text in the textbox, please let me know what i am doing wrong I want it to save first then send out an email to the user.

```
     $con = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
     if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

      mysql_select_db("database", $con);

  $sql="INSERT INTO table(`feild1`, `feild2`)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[User]','$_POST[QueryDes]')";
     if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
       {
       die('Error: '. mysql_error());
       }
       echo "1 record added";
```

the above code is to insert.

```
     if (isset($_POST['dropdown']))
     {
       //send email
       $email = $_POST['dropdown'] ;
       $subject = "You have submitted your query  ";
        $message = "Thank you for using the online query facility. We will attend to your query as soon as possible."; 


        $from = "me@mail.com";
      $headers = "From:" .$from;
     mail($email, $subject,$message, $headers);
```

and this code above is to send the email.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0           Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <head>
   <meta content="en-za" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Query</title>
  </head>

  <body>

     <form action="log2.php" method="post">
UserName&nbsp; <select name="User" style="width: 156px">
<option value="">--SELECT--</option>
<option value="myself@mymail.com">Me</option>
      Query Description&nbsp;<input name="QueryDes" style="width: 196px" type="text" />&nbsp;
      &nbsp;<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Log Call" style="width: 78px" />
      </form>

      </body>

   </html>
```

This is the html of the form

Comment: Do you mean you want to fetch the value _AND_ the content of the dropdown? like <option value="email">username</option> and you want both username and email? BTW, nice SQL injection you got there

Comment: Can you please add the html code for the FORM and any data you get from the form into the PHP.

Comment: @Damien, No i just need the value and need to email to the value of the dropdown lol i will sanitize it once i get this to work

Comment: Well, so how do you get the ursername? would you be so kind to put all what is needed to spot the problem for you? From your code so far, I just see an unsafe query and a mailing snippet using just one form value (supposedly the email)

Comment: @Damien I hope i have put up the necessary code and you will have to forgive me if my php is bad im still learning and im new at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, correct (see the quotes in array indexes) and escape (as @footy already told you) your query  **[insert "better using prepared statements" phrase here]:**

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['User']);
$request = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['QueryDes']);
$sql="INSERT INTO table(`feild1`, `feild2`) VALUES ('$user','$request')";
```

Then, you have no `$_POST['drowpdown']` whatsoever, so your `isset()` would never evaluate to TRUE. If you meant to refer to the dropdown html input field, you're on the wrong track. You don't call a text input like `$_POST['input']`, don't you?

Also, since you give it an empty value (which you presumably don't want to use in your mailing), you can do something like

```
    if($_POST['User'] != '')
    {
       $email = $_POST['User']
       // You should also check if the mail is valid. Try using the filter_var() provided by
       // PHP, or some fancy regex you find everywhere

       $subject = "You have submitted your query  ";
       $message = "Thank you for using the online query facility. We will attend to your query as soon as possible.";
       $from = "me@mail.com";
       $headers = "From:" .$from;

       if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
       {

          // better option is querying your database here, since you're going to insert an empty value for the mail, otherwise.

          if(mail($email, $subject,$message, $headers))
          {
            echo 'Mail sent!';
          }
          else
          {
            echo 'Error in sending your mail!';
          }
       }
       else
       {
          echo 'Invalid email';
       }
}
```

**On second thought**, insert in your database a non-empty value for the $_POST['User'] field, so you should do that check before running your query.

Answer (score 1):

An **IMPORTANT** thing you should never do is to insert values directly into the database. In your code dont use `$_POST` directly. Why? There are many reasons, like [SQL Injection Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), Data Inconsistency etc. Use a function like [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or other functions available (another topic for discussion)

To Answer your question, you would need an active database present in your server (prefereably MySQL my fav :P). You can follow the [tutorial here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php13p3.html) or [here](http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php) to insert values before mailing to the user his details. Just google it.

> Open a connection to MySQL
>
> Specify the database we want to open
>
> Set up a SQL Statement that can be used to add records to the database
>   table
>
> Use mysql_query( ) again, but this time to add records to the table
>
> Close the connection

Comment: i have an active connection to my database and yes i am using a MYSQL database :) and I always close my connection

Comment: mysql_escape_string function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 4.3.0 Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. Do you mean mysql_real_escape_string?